# Corda Drain mode does not prevent the flows to start

Tags: corda

Reading the documentation of Corda I thought that the drain mode should not allow any flows to be started on a node until the drain mode is disabled. However seems not to be the case, at least when I run my flows from a ServiceHub. Here is what I have tried:

I run my cordapp with deployNodes task. In the corda shell I run `run setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled enabled: true`. Then I run a flow through ServiceHub which updates an existing state in that node, and without undraining the node I query vault and see that the state was successfully updated. So I am really confused. How does actually the draining works?

What I really want to achieve is to create a small utility program to safely shutdown the node, or fail after some time of trying. here is the code:

```
class ShutdownOrFailHelper {

private val sleepInterval = 1_000L
private val maxSleepTimes = 120
private var count = 0

fun run(args: Array<String>) {
    val connection = RPCConnector().connect(args)
    val proxy = connection.proxy
    val nodeInfo = proxy.nodeInfo()

    proxy.setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled(true)
    do {
        val pendingSize = proxy.stateMachinesSnapshot().size

        if(pendingSize == 0){
            proxy.shutdown()
            println("Done")
            break
        }
        Thread.sleep(sleepInterval)
        count++
        println("$pendingSize flows are running. Waiting flows to finish on $nodeInfo")

        if(count > maxSleepTimes){
            println("Node still has $pendingSize flows running. Give up waiting..")
            proxy.setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled(false)
            connection.notifyServerAndClose()
            exitProcess(1)
        }
    } while (pendingSize != 0)
}}
```

But for this to work properly I need to make sure that after `proxy.setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled(true)` it is not possible to start any more flows, but actually even after this I am able to start flows. And I really don't understand what is the purpose of drain mode then...

Answer (score 0):

Flow draining mode comes into the picture as part of your cordapps / corda upgrading strategy only.

This mode would complete outstanding flows while queuing up new start flow messages, and then signal when this is completed, so that an operator can proceed with a clean shutdown.

The above would allow an operator to know when it is safe to shut the node down and replace the JARs.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to be more concrete what I want to achieve. what actually confuses me is that in draining mode the flows do not queue, they start as usual and complete as usual, so I really don't understand what the draining mode is.

Comment: Hi looks to be like a bug. we only stop flows triggered via RPC. Raised a bug - https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6486.